# Are there any accessibility guidelines to compare background color of a button with background color of a page?

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag2.0, color-blindness

Color of my button:#73c998
Background color of my page: #2C6C9E

While this tool below tests the colors as if one of them was a text color, do we have anything for background to background comparison?

See link:  http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%09%2373c998-on-%232C6C9E

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to? The guidelines are for text on background color, does the button not have any text?

Comment: No there isn't. Text provides information so there are guidelines for contrast ratio text vs background. There's also a guideline about color of link text vs color of surrounding text because links are the foundation of the web. But contrast ratio of background page vs background button isn't the important part: it's the contrast ratio of text vs background in the button that is important. Having the form of a button or not isn't related to accessibility, it isn't a problem by itself: it can be a black area over black background, everybody will find the yellow text...